# Swift - Changing font size inside label

Tags: ios, swift

I have a label where there is text which should be bold and with another font size. Is there any possibility to do it like the line break ("Hello \n World!") with a command or do I have to make another label for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the API for [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/index.html) -- it allows you to create a string that specifies portions of the string that should be styled with specific text styles and/or fonts. The resulting object can be used instead of a plain string with `UILabel` (and other UI elements) by setting the label's `attributedText` property instead of the usual `text` property.

To make just the word "bold" appear in **18 point bold**, try something like the following:

```
var label = UILabel()
let bigBoldFont = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(18.0)

var attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "This text is bold.")
attrString.addAttribute(kCTFontAttributeName, value: bigBoldFont, range: NSMakeRange(13, 4))

label.attributedText = attrString
```

The range specified determines the portion of the string to which the named attributed (in this case, the font) should be applied. And note that the parameters to NSMakeRange are the starting character position and the length of the range.